# video.addEventListener("ended", endedFunction); "ended" event listener not working

Tags: javascript, events, listener, media

I am writing JS code on event listener in VScode. Event listener like - canplay, play, pause, playing worked just fine. But (ended) not working.

Here is the code below-->

```js
video.addEventListener("ended", endedFunction);
function endedFunction(event) //? parameter in optional
{
  console.log("Ended");
  console.log(event);
}
```

I tried to rewrite the function in different ways as I thought it was a problem regarding the function. But the problem was not about the function.

Comment: please share the relevant code where you added video element and how you accessed it